# Text Selection in Web Browser?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, mouse

When using a web browser (Chrome/Firefox etc) I have the ability to make the text cursor appear wherever I click using the mouse/trackpad. For example, I can select the side of this text box and a text cursor (the size of the box) will appear. Basically wherever there is text, if I click on it using the default cursor, or the text selector cursor, the flashing text indicator will appear.

[image]

[image]

Normally you can click and drag using the text selector cursor, but the flashing indicator does not appear. How do I control/disable this?

Comment: Which flashing text indicator?

Answer (score 0):

This feature is called *caret browsing*. It can be turned off by pressing <kbd>F7</kbd>. A confirmation dialog may appear.